# How to Reference Spark Broadcast Variables Outside of Scope

Tags: scala, apache-spark

All the examples I've seen for Spark broadcast variables define them in the scope of the functions using them (`map()`, `join()`, etc.). I would like to use both a `map()` function and `mapPartitions()` function that reference a broadcast variable, but I would like to modularize them so I can use the same functions for unit testing purposes.

- How can I accomplish this?

A thought I had was to curry the function so that I pass a reference to the broadcast variable when using either a `map` or `mapPartitions` call.

- Are there any performance implications by passing around the reference to the broadcast variable that are not normally found when defining the functions inside the original scope?

I had something like this in mind (pseudo-code):

```
// firstFile.scala
// ---------------

def mapper(bcast: Broadcast)(row: SomeRow): Int = {
  bcast.value(row._1)
}

def mapMyPartition(bcast: Broadcast)(iter: Iterator): Iterator {
  val broadcastVariable = bcast.value

  for {
    i <- iter
  } yield broadcastVariable(i)
})


// secondFile.scala
// ----------------

import firstFile.{mapMyPartition, mapper}

val bcastVariable = sc.broadcast(Map(0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3))

rdd
 .map(mapper(bcastVariable))
 .mapPartitions(mapMyPartition(bcastVariable))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should work fine. In both cases the function passed to `map{Partitions}` will contain a reference to the broadcast variable itself when serialized, but not to its value, and only call `bcast.value` when calculated on the node.

What needs to be avoided is something like

```
def mapper(bcast: Broadcast): SomeRow => Int = {
  val value = bcast.value
  row => value(row._1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing this correctly. You just have to remember to pass the broadcast reference and not the value itself. Using your example the difference might be shown as follows:

a) efficient way:

```
// the whole Map[Int, Int] is serialized and sent to every worker
val bcastVariable = sc.broadcast(Map(0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3)) 

rdd
.map(mapper(bcastVariable)) // only the reference to the Map[Int, Int] is serialized and sent to every worker
.mapPartitions(mapMyPartition(bcastVariable)) // only the reference to the Map[Int, Int] is serialized and sent to every worker
```

b) inefficient way:

```
// the whole Map[Int, Int] is serialized and sent to every worker
val bcastVariable = sc.broadcast(Map(0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3)) 

rdd
.map(mapper(bcastVariable.value)) // the whole Map[Int, Int] is serialized and sent to every worker
.mapPartitions(mapMyPartition(bcastVariable.value)) // the whole Map[Int, Int] is serialized and sent to every worker
```

Of course in the second example `mapper` and `mapMyPartition` would have slightly different signature.